# What is the purpose of 'Class.forName("MY_JDBC_DRIVER")'?

Tags: java, jdbc

I understand that class loading is useful for load the class at runtime with its class name.

However while using JDBC in our project we know which driver we are going to use and mostly driver manager string is hard coded.

My question is: Why are we loading driver using `Class.forName("JDBC_DRIVER")` here?
Why can't we go ahead adding the driver in class path? since we know which driver jar we are going to use.

I believe `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER)` will load the Driver into `DriverManager`. Is it the only reason?

**Edit 1:**

The [`DriverManager` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) states that

> As part of its(DriverManager) initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property.
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.

Then when I use other than oracle driver; do I need to change the driver name string in system property?

Comment: Group, Thanks. Now I understood that class.forName() is useful to load a class compare to other mechanisms like calling its static method or creating a instance of that class.  This way we can ensure that executing some functionalities only once using static block while loading.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of: with modern JDBC drivers and a current JDK (at least Java 6) the call to `Class.forName()` is no longer necessary. [JDBC driver classes are now located](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) using the [service provider mechanism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider). You *should* be able to simply remove that call and leave the rest of the code unchanged and it should continue to work.

If you're not using a current JDK (or if you have a JDBC driver that does *not* have the appropriate files set up to use that mechanism) then the driver needs to be registered with the `DriverManager` using [`registerDriver`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29). That method is *usually* called from the static initializer block of the actual driver class, which gets triggered when the class is first loaded, so issuing the `Class.forName()` ensures that the driver registers itself (if it wasn't already done).

And no matter if you use `Class.forName()` or the new service provider mechanism, you will *always* need the JDBC driver on the classpath (or available via some `ClassLoader` at runtime, at least).

**tl;dr**: yes, the *only* use of that `Class.forName()` call is to ensure the driver is registered. If you use a current JDK and current JDBC drivers, then this call should no longer be necesary.

Comment: Yes! in java6 without Class.forName() line; DriverManager is able to create Connection for oracle driver. I just tested. It is done via loadInitialDrivers() :: DriverManager. Thanks!

Comment: @Joachim, JustinK's comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while#comment-9863309 states that as for pre JDBC 4, `Class.forName` is **only needed when** the driver isn't on the classpath. Why does JustinK's comment directly contradict your quote that says we "will always need the JDBC driver on the classpath"?

Comment: @Pacerier: JustinK is talking about having the driver on the classpath *while building your code*. That should never be necessary unless you somehow access the driver class directly (which you might need it you access some non-standard features, but is rather unlikely otherwise). At runtime, you need to have the driver on the classpath (or maybe on a custom classloader, if you prefer, but that's pretty much the same thing effectively) no matter how you access it, otherwise it couldn't be loaded.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, True on that, and yes since custom classloaders are widely used, your statement "you will always need the JDBC driver on the classpath" should be edited. It is wrong because we don't need the driver on the classpath at all, since using a classloader, we can load the JDBC driver through a file/memory/network/user-input. (btw apologies for the late reply, the ":" char doesn't seem to work with the "@")

Answer (score 14):

The Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER) call will register your JDBC driver in the DriverManager, so you can address it by url, such as "jdbc:odbc:Database" and so on...

Usually the driver class has static initialization code like this, which is invoked on Class.forName():

```
 public class Driver implements java.sql.Driver {
   static {
     try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
     } catch (SQLException E) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
     }
   }
 }
```

You still have to put JDBC driver jar into the classpath.

As an alternative, you can use database specific DataSource, then you can declaratively specify the datasource type, for example in Spring context or in your Web server JNDI. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/SetupDataSourceforMySQL.htm).

Comment: technically this is invoked when the Class is loaded, not necessarily on `Class.forName()` which is just one way to force an unloaded class to be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Putting a class in the classpath is not sufficient to have it loaded by the class loader. And the driver class must be loaded to ensure that it's registered to the JDBC API. BTW, for `Class.forName` to work, the driver class **must** be in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

In many industrial applications, we would like to abstract the data access layer from the rest of code, by pulling such information in a form of a property file/configuration file. In those cases, we might need to use something as you have done.

For e.g. we can use the JDBC interface classes to write the code to access the database, where you could configure the properties by selecting which technology you want to use as a database (e.g. ojdbc driver, or mysql jdbc driver, etc.) In those cases you can load the class using such method.