# What is a JDBC driver manager?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is a Driver Manager and why is it required when you use JDBC to connect to a database?
I tried connecting to the database without the given below statement:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

But it fails. So, what does this line of code do when connecting to mysql database using java?

Comment: With recent driver versions and Java 6 / JDBC 4 or higher that line is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose 'Class.forName("MY\_JDBC\_DRIVER")'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662902/what-is-the-purpose-class-fornamemy-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 1):

If you check  the Oracle docs you will get the clear picture.

[The basic service for managing a set of JDBC drivers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Also from [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

> First, you need to establish a connection with the data source you
> want to use. A data source can be a DBMS, a legacy file system, or
> some other source of data with a corresponding JDBC driver. Typically,
> a JDBC application connects to a target data source using one of two
> classes:
>
> • **DriverManager:** This fully implemented class connects an
> application to a data source, which is specified by a database URL.
> When this class first attempts to establish a connection, it
> automatically loads any JDBC 4.0 drivers found within the class path.
> Note that your application must manually load any JDBC drivers prior
> to version 4.0.
>
> • **DataSource**: This interface is preferred over
> DriverManager because it allows details about the underlying data
> source to be transparent to your application. A DataSource object's
> properties are set so that it represents a particular data source. See
> Connecting with DataSource Objects for more information. For more
> information about developing applications with the DataSource class,
> see the latest The Java EE Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code returns a new object of driver class loaded into memory.

`DriverManager` class aids to connect to data source.
Register and De-register driver class.
Set login time out counter.