# PostgreSQL JDBC Driver not working for Heroku DB Connection

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, jdbc

I have a class that tries to connect to a Heroku database:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        System.out.println("Conectando ao banco");
        try {           
            return DriverManager.getConnection("connectionstring", "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What it returns is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for
>   jdbc:postgres://osnvehqhufnxzr:TS3Qt37c_HHbGRNKw3yk7g88fp@ec2-54-225-93-34.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d39mfq0odt56bv

I already tried **postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc3.jar** and **postgresql-9.4.1209.jre6.jar**
in the Build Path of the project. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Someone moderator can delete this question?

Comment: Can you not find the spot to delete the question yourself?
Posting a comment is not the way to get a moderator's attention.
Rather, post a request for help on the "meta" site.

Comment: Fixed code formatting; made minor grammar upgrades.

Comment: Using Block-quote for errors will make it readable in question.  Please try to avoid a scroll bar in your question always and make everything fit in the screen - either code or error.  Don't post sensitive information like id, user name or passwords in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, *System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL")* returns it in server and it does the correct configuration of login and password.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException 
{   
String urlDB = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");          
return DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `postgresql` in your JDBC URL and not `postgres`.

Also, you need to change your DB password (because you posted it publicly) by running this command:

```
$ heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset
```

Comment: Also worth noting that Heroku provides a `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` for you if you are using the standard buildpack or deploy tools. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url

Comment: I was using the default URL (postgres://...) and adding jdbc: in front of it... omg I tried to view the JDBC_DATABASE_URL but I could not do the steps of the tutorial: I opened console, and logged, after that inserted  $heroku run echo \$JDBC_DATABASE_URL but it returns !Error no app specified, how to do it?

Comment: PostgreSQL itself supports both `postgres` and `postgresql`. But JDBC needs the exact string `postgresql` to locate the driver.

Comment: "no app specified" means you are not in the correct directory. try adding `-a <app>` to the command but replace `<app>` with your app-name

Comment: also, what tutorial?

Comment: From the link you pasted "Using the JDBC_DATABASE_URL", the steps.

Comment: Did you try putting `postgresql` into your app?

Comment: In my app? In dashboard the database that I've created appears as a app itself. I have that other that was my application where I upload my war file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121092/discussion-between-jamesb-and-codefinger).

Comment: the URL needs to be `jdbc:postgresql://...`

Comment: In your post you write `jdbc:postgres://...`. note the `ql`

Comment: Can I test it locally? Without uploading a war file every time I wanna test any change?

Comment: Read the instructions in the previous link for connecting remotely https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the driver class first by the class loader:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
```

---

Also see: [What is the purpose of 'Class.forName("MY_JDBC_DRIVER")'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662902/what-is-the-purpose-of-class-fornamemy-jdbc-driver)

Comment: Was not only until the version 3 of JDBC? I read somewhere newer versions don't need it. Adding it the errors persists.

Comment: public Connection getConnection() {  
  try {  
   try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {    
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgres://osnvehqhufnxzr:TS3Qt37c_HHbGRNKw3yk7g88fp@ec2-54-225-93-34.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d39mfq0odt56bv", "postgres", "root");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

Comment: @JamesB Never read about that. Make sure you properly included the required jar files into the classpath upon running.

Comment: Yes I did. Jars are in the library.

Comment: @JamesB If the database is hosted on Amazon AWS then It might require different driver than the normal one.